# Full screen/minimalised web design from load

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

So I'm currently building a radio player purely for mobile web browsing (a unique version a better UX experience). However I seem to be drawing to a dead end on this part of the design brief..

Can you get Safari and others to display full screen from the original load? I know it's possible once you're scrolling away, but I'm talking about having everything minimalised (even better full screen) from the second it loads. Having a chunky url bar and page control options scattered over the design is ruining the experience.

Thanks.

Comment: What you need is a native app.

Comment: @noisypixy This is already being worked on, it's more for providing a web solution too

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to control the users browser to become full size. Am I right?
That shouldn't be possible, because it is in the users favour to decide which size and where to place the browser. Some people don't even fullsize their browser, because they need more space.

Comment: On a smart device (mobile browser) - I'm talking about shrinking down the url bar and other tools.. this is a perfect example of it https://uploadir.com/u/riaqi71z.png

Comment: I know that this happens when you save the website to your screen as an "app". There is a function where you can save websites as "webapps". Then there is no url bar! But you can't control it with any script, because it is the users decision.

Comment: Never realised you could get it that bare/full screen, thanks. After more extensive searching I've found out that Apple stopped allowing minimal-ui after iOS 8. As I described before; scrolling get's it to work.. however this is the only reminiscence left of minimal-ui now.